# rsyslog: rsyslog mailing list still active, otherwise where to ask for rsyslog advanced syntax experts

Tags: rsyslog

rsyslog aficionados,

Is the rsyslog mailing list still active?  I signed up for this mailing list over a week ago at
https://lists.adiscon.net/mailman/listinfo/rsyslog, never heard back.

I'm on a few other mailing lists, so I know how to sign up for a mailing list.

I notice on:

https://www.rsyslog.com/what-are-your-thoughts-regarding-current-and-potential-rsyslog-support-channels/

That there's a consideration of shutting down the web forums and possibly the rsyslog mailing list. Is that why I have not heard back;  the rsyslog mailing list is inactive?

I had a situation where a particular remote syslog target wants its syslog events in UTC, while all local targets should remain in local time.  I looked at:

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5367831 and
https://access.redhat.com/articles/3549872#clientrhel7
[https://rsyslog.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rainerscript/#:~:text=RainerScript%20is%20a%20scripting%20language,because%20that%27s%20somebody%20else%27s%20trademark](https://rsyslog.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rainerscript/#:%7E:text=RainerScript%20is%20a%20scripting%20language,because%20that%27s%20somebody%20else%27s%20trademark).

So I think I have the syntax all worked out and it seems to work.  But I wanted someone that knows the rsyslog advanced syslog better than me to review and see if it all looks good.  Hence, the desire to join the rsyslog mailing list.

Spike White

I requested access to the mailing list on https://lists.adiscon.net/mailman/listinfo/rsyslog, waited a week and got no response.